# Content overlapping the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to design a long scrolling website using bootstrap and I can't find a way to actually to place more than one image without them actually overlapping each other. What I'm looking for is something similar to this 
https://www.flickr.com/

Any help would be much appreciated.

This is the CSS I used to make the image full screen but for some reason everything I add after that will just pile up on it and not underneath it.

```
.bg-img{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        z-index: -100;
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }
```

Edit: made code visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When positioning an image to be `absolute` it does not take up any space in the flow. This way it hides whatever comes after it.

One solution would be to add a wrapper and also use viewport units. [Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Voreny/9m45q0yf/)

```
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.bg-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -100;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolute is your issue here, this takes everything out of flow so none of the elements are aware of each other. Try floating or diplay: inline-block etc.